# Why use an extension on config/database.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm inheriting a project that uses `config/database.yml.sqlite` and `config/database.yml.psql` instead of `config/database.yml`.

Why is this done and how should I use it?

If I just run `rake db:create` rails is looking for a `config/database.yml`. I've tried looking for a way to specify the name of the config file but no luck.

I could just ask the people I'm inheriting the code from but after a bit of googling around I see this pattern in other projects and think that it'd be nice if SO had an answer.

Comment: I think they just have the extension to coexist in the directory. So if you want to use SQLite in your project you have to rename the `database.yml.sqlite` into `database.yml`. The same applies if you want to use Postgresql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is often quite normal to add database.yml to your .gitignore file, because it can contain passwords etc, and so ought to be kept out of the Git repo.

In this case, it is useful to keep an example database.yml file *in* the repo, showing the settings you would want for, say a Postgres database if you are going to use that, or a Sqlite database if you prefer that for your development work. Then you can get set up quickly once you've cloned the repo.

All you have to do is run:

```
cp config/database.yml.psql config/database.yml
```

then add your own passwords for your local development database into database.yml, which will then stay out of the repo and not be shared with any other developers working on the same project.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually never seen that pattern. It sounds to me that those other YAML files are pre-encoded for the target database - pre-configured so to speak.

The same result could be achieved by a single YAML file with extensive documented blocks - "here is a sqlite block, here is a Postgres block", etc.